# Como juntar a query string na paginação do Laravel 4?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Como faço para juntar query string na paginação do laravel 4?

Por exemplo: tenho uma listagem de dados e nessa mesma tela tenho um filtro de pesquisa. Quando envio um get para solicitar o filtro na lista pela url 
`http://localhost/lista-de-produtos?marca=1`,
os dados são listados como solicitado, mas quando vou para página 2 o paginate retira o parâmetro marca=1 da url e adiciona pag=2, então o filtro não funciona.

Segue o código da consulta:

```
$registros = Produtos::where(function ($query) {
    if (Input::has('nome')) {

        $nome = Input::get('nome');

        $query->where('nome', 'LIKE', "%{$nome}%");

    } 

    if (Input::has('marca')){
        $marcaId = Input::get('marca');

        $query->where('marca_id', '=', $marcaId);
    }

})->paginate(20);
```

Comment: Já teve gente que usou `http_build_query` pra fazer isso. Mas no Laravel não precisa. É tudo bonito. Veja a resposta ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No laravel existe um método chamado `appends`, onde você passa um array, que representará os dados que irão juntamente com o atribute `page` na url.

Exemplo:

```
User::where('admin', '=', 0)->paginate()->appends(Input::except('page'));
```

Nesse caso, o `Input::except` encarregará de adicionar todos da query string atual na sua paginação.

Isso é muito útil em casos de pesquisas com paginação, como no Google.

Ao invés de excepts, você também pode usar `Input::all()`.

## Atualização

Em versões mais recentes no Laravel 5, não foi necessário fazer isso. Mas caso necessite, a lógica é a mesma:

```
User::where('admin', '=', 0)->paginate()->appends($request->all());
```

Answer (score 2):

O model **Produtos** não conhece os parâmetros passados na filtragem. Para que passe a identificá-los, é preciso instruí-lo para repasse os parâmetros na construção dos links de paginação.

Isso é feito usando o método **appends** (Veja a [documentação do Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/pagination)).
Por exemplo, no blade, se você estiver usando assim:

```
{{ $registros->links() }}
```

Então implemente assim:

```
{{ $registros->appends([
  'nome'  => Request::input('nome'),
  'marca'  => Request::input('marca'),
])->links() }}
```

ou assim se for laravel 5.6+:

```
{{ $registros->appends(request()->all())->links() }}
```

ou diretamente no model:

```
Produtos::when(...)->appends(request()->all())->paginate(20);
```

Dessa forma, a paginação irá incluir as chaves do array como parâmetros na querystring dos links.